# Maximal value in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic in the unit disc $D = \lbrace z: |z|<1 \rbrace$ and continuous in the corresponding closed disc $\overline{D}=\lbrace z: |z| \leq 1 \rbrace.$ Suppose also that $f(z)/z^7$ can be extended to be analytic in all of $D$ (including the origin). If $|f(z)| \leq 4 in \overline{D}$, what is the maximal value that |$f(-0.5-0.5i)|$ can assume under these conditions?

Comment: What is the context? What have you tried? What you do you mean by $|f(z)| \le 4 in \overline{D}$? What does it mean to be less than a multiple of a closed disk?

Comment: I think that is supposed to mean $|f(z)| \leq 4$ for $z \in \overline{D}$.